# ЧПУ вида nazvanie.html

Tags: чпу

При создании статьи в отдельное поле в БД у меня вписывается на транслите название статьи.
А вот как сделать так чтобы статья открывалась не по адресу http://site.ru/articles.php?id=ID а по адресу http://site.ru/nazvanie.html ?
Статья выводится так

---

```
if($id)
{
$counts = @ mysql_result(mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `articles` WHERE `id`='.$id.' AND `moderation`="1";'), 0);
if($counts==0) {
echo '<div class="alert alert-error">Статьи не существует!</div>';
echo '</article>';
require 'system/foot.php';
exit;
}
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `id`='".$id."' AND `moderation`='1'"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В файле .htaccess, в корне сайта, добавить запись

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /articles.php?name=$1 [L]
```

И немного изменить запрос к БД. 
Вместо

```
id='.$id.'
```

написать

```
translite_name="'.mysql_escape_string($_GET['name']).'"
```

Comment: Только вот как определить что статьи не существует?

Comment: Что-то вроде этого:
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `translite_name`="'.mysql_escape_string($_GET['name']).'" AND `moderation`='1'"));
if(!$row['ID'])
{
echo '<div class="alert alert-error">Статьи не существует!</div>';
echo '</article>';
require 'system/foot.php';
exit;
}

И код 
if($id)
{
....
}
Убрать совсем

Comment: Точнее if(!$row['chpy'])

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ articles.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

при наборе **http://site.ru/nazvanie.html**

```
$_GET["id"] = "nazvanie.html";
```

Comment: Если делать по-твоему то работает только так - http://site.ru/nazvanie.html?id=ID

Comment: дак ты не правильно делаешь же...

Comment: Да уже все нормально, работает.